# How can I create a LinkedIn like Tab Bar selection animation in iOS using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

The current iOS LinkedIn app's UITabBar fills up the UITabBarItem image on selection. The filling up of the UITabBarItem image is animated. How can I replicate that animation using Swift?

Initially when not selected the image just has an outline with no fill. On selection the image fills up from the middle (animated) with a color leading to filled image.

Comment: This is too broad. You need to show / explain in detail what you are trying to do, not just reference *some* other app. And even then you might end up just posting a "gimme teh codez" question

Comment: @luk2302 I have edited my question. Guess it makes more sense now

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily achieve this by using the `UIImageView`'s `highlightedAnimationImages` along with an `animationRepeatCount = 0`

If you don't want to have many images instead of only 1, you can subclass UIImageView and animate an additional colored mask layer when highlighted.

You can also look for frameworks like [Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios) to use animations

Comment: This animation is happening on the UITabBarItem image. It does not have a UIImageView.